# Simple AM-GM Inequality doubt

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Can you just fill the gap in the following solution?
The AM-GM Inequality was applied on which terms?

**Problem**
Let x, y,z be real numbers satisfying $x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + xyz = 4$. Show that:
$$\sqrt{2-x} \ge \frac{y+z}{2}$$
**Solution**
[image]

Apologies for an unclear image.

Comment: What is the question of your problem?

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Any clues now?

Comment: You have your answer now but please remind yourself that it is highly recommended to write your question in latex and also, your question should be clear. If these requirements don't meet, it is highly possible that your question will be closed.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time, it's applied on $\frac{x^4}2, \frac{y^4}2, \frac{y^4}2, \frac12$. For others, you can observe yourself now, right?

Comment: Thank you very much.